# Right to left Flickable

Tags: qt, qml, right-to-left, flickable

when i add a child into `Flickable` it anchors that to the left of whole control,but i want `flickable`'s child anchors to the right of whole control (i think when there is anything inside flickable its flickableItem implicitWidth affects the whole controls width thats why i cant use `anchors.right = parent.right` ), there is no `layoutDirection` property in `Flickable` and `LayoutMirroring` is not working in flickable, how can i force Flickable to paint child from right margin of its body?
this is my flickable control :

```
// ScrollableItem.qml

Flickable{
    id:root
    contentWidth: pane.implicitWidth
    contentHeight: pane.implicitHeight
    boundsBehavior: Flickable.StopAtBounds
    flickableDirection: Flickable.AutoFlickIfNeeded
    default property alias content : pane.contentItem

    Pane{
        id:pane
    }
    ScrollIndicator.vertical: ScrollIndicator{

    }
    ScrollIndicator.horizontal: ScrollIndicator{

    }
}
```

and i use it like this :

```
ScrollableItem{
   width : parent.width
   height : parent.height
   RowLayout{
      spacing: 500
      layoutDirection: Qt.RightToLeft
      Button{
      }
      Button{
      }
      Button{
      }
   }
}
```

Qml dont care about `width : parent.width` of `ScrollableItem` and if i set width inside control it wont flick , i tried to use anchors.right in child's too but didnt work. is there anyway to force flickable child to flow from right of screen?

**UPDATE** : let me show you in a picture
 [image]

you see where pane anchored? anchoring pane to right is impossible and there is no layout direction and width of pane is depend on child width which is a rowLayout so if pane width is lower than flickable width it will always drawn on the left edge of flickable which i want to drawn in right edge of flickable

Comment: Doc says *Note: Due to an implementation detail, items placed inside a Flickable cannot anchor to the Flickable. Instead, use parent, which refers to the Flickable's contentItem. The size of the content item is determined by contentWidth and contentHeight.*

Comment: Can you explain more what you want to achieve exactly? Flickable does not really flow anything. Do you want the content to be scrolled on its right end by default? Have you tried to play with content position?

Comment: @ymoreau is this image enough detailed?

Comment: Much clearer yes, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, a [Flickable](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-flickable.html) should not logically have anchoring capabilities.
So you need to explicitly move the [Flickable](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-flickable.html) to the right by :

```
// ScrollableItem.qml
Flickable{
    id:root
    contentWidth: pane.implicitWidth
    contentHeight: pane.implicitHeight
    boundsBehavior: Flickable.StopAtBounds
    flickableDirection: Flickable.AutoFlickIfNeeded
    default property alias content : pane.contentItem
    leftMargin: pane.contentWidth >= root.width ? 0 : root.width - pane.contentWidth
    contentX:  pane.mirrored ? pane.width : 0;
    property var lastWidth : 0

    Pane{
        id:pane
    }

    onWidthChanged: {
        contentX += lastWidth-width
        lastWidth = width;
    }

    ScrollIndicator.vertical: ScrollIndicator{}
    ScrollIndicator.horizontal: ScrollIndicator{}
}
```

and i use it like this :

```
    ScrollableItem{
       width : parent.width
       height : parent.height

       LayoutMirroring.enabled: true
       LayoutMirroring.childrenInherit: true

       RowLayout{
          spacing: 500
          layoutDirection: Qt.RightToLeft
          Button{
          }
          Button{
          }
          Button{
          }
       }
    }
```

This works quite well for me. When the `pane` has smaller width than the [Flickable](http://[Flickable][1]), you should add the remaining space to `leftMargin` to keep the content at the right side.

Comment: this answer is really better than mine,but has problem with resizing application, when you resize , content goes to the left of flickable

Comment: Yes, I noticed the problem. we will find a way. I should set contentX on resize. This should do the trick. let me see

Comment: It doesn't work for me. flicking stops at some point by your edit.